# Shape is some how becoming 224,224,1,1 hence causing a negative dimension by convolutional Layer

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification

X is numpy array of images of shape (5200,224,224,3) and y is a numpy array of labels 0,1,2,3 and 4. This is my code -

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))

def format_example(image, label):
\# Make image color values to be float.
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
\# Make image color values to be in \[0..1\] range.
image = image / 255.
return image, label

dataset = dataset.map(format_example)

# Set the train, test and validation sizes

train_size = int(0.7 \* len(X))
test_size = int(0.15 \* len(X))
val_size = int(0.15 \* len(X))

# Shuffle the dataset and split into train, validation, and test sets

dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(X))
train_dataset = dataset.take(train_size)
validation_dataset = dataset.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test_dataset = dataset.skip(train_size + val_size).take(test_size)

# Convert the images to grayscale

def rgb_to_gray(image, label):
image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
return image, label

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(rgb_to_gray)
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.map(rgb_to_gray)
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(rgb_to_gray)

\#batching and prefetching
BATCH_SIZE=32
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

def one_hot_encode(labels, num_classes):
labels = tf.squeeze(labels, axis=-1)  # remove the extra dimension
one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes)
return one_hot

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, one_hot_encode(y, num_classes=5)))
validation_dataset = validation_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, one_hot_encode(y, num_classes=5)))
test_dataset = test_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x, one_hot_encode(y, num_classes=5)))

model = keras.Sequential(\[
keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 1)),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
keras.layers.Flatten(),
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
\])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=\['accuracy'\])

steps_per_epoch = train_size // BATCH_SIZE
validation_steps = val_size // BATCH_SIZE if val_size // BATCH_SIZE else 1

print('steps_per_epoch:', steps_per_epoch)
print('validation_steps:', validation_steps)

initial_epochs=20
history = model.fit(
x=train_dataset.repeat(),
validation_data=validation_dataset.repeat(),
epochs=initial_epochs,
steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
validation_steps=validation_steps,
verbose=1
)
```

### This is my error-

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-30-e2eba87266d2> in <cell line: 2>()
> 1 initial_epochs=20
> 2 training_history = model.fit(
> 3     x=train_dataset.repeat(),
> 4     validation_data=validation_dataset.repeat(),
> 5     epochs=initial_epochs,
>
> 1 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__test_function(iterator)
> 13                 try:
> 14                     do_return = True
> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
> 16                 except:
> 17                     do_return = False
>
> ValueError: in user code:
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1852, in test_function  *
> return step_function(self, iterator)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1836, in step_function  **
> outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1824, in run_step  **
> outputs = model.test_step(data)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1788, in test_step
> y_pred = self(x, training=False)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
>
> ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'conv2d_4' (type Conv2D).
>
> Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node sequential_1/conv2d_4/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](sequential_1/ExpandDims, sequential_1/conv2d_4/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [224,224,1,1], [3,3,1,32].
>
> Call arguments received by layer 'conv2d_4' (type Conv2D):
> inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(224, 224, 1, 1), dtype=float32)

The model should have just trained because I checked the shape it ws 224,224,1 so I don't know what's the issue

Comment: Hi @athul srinivas, Please add `padding=same` in `Conv2D` layers (`tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same') ` in your model definition and try running your code again. Let us know if the issue still persists.